# In SQL Server, how to get last inserted records ID's when batch update is done?

Tags: sql-server, mssql-jdbc

In SQL Server, i am inserting multiple records into table using batch update. How do i get back the ID's (unique primary key) which is being created after batch update?

If I insert one record, I can get the last inserted using `IDENT(tableName)`. I am not sure how to get if I do batch update. Please help.

For example, I have student table, with ROLE NO and NAME. ROLE NO is auto incremented by 1, as soon I insert the names into DB using java program. I will add 3 rows at a time using batch update from my java code. In DB, it gets added with ROLE NO 2, 3 and 4. How do I get these newly generated ID in my java program, please help

I tried getting ids using getgeneratedkeys method after I do executebatch. I get exception. Is batch update + get generated keys supported.?

Comment: What kind of exception was raised? Post your java code used for batch process.

Comment: You mean batch **INSERT**, right? Because an update requires a row to already exist, and if it already exists, it already has an `ID` which isn't changed during the update ...

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server when you do an insert there is an extra option your query; `OUTPUT`. This will let you capture back the data you inserted into the table - including your id's. You have to insert them into a temporary table; so something like this (with your table/ column names will get you there.

```
declare @MyNewRoles Table (Name, RoleNo)

insert into tblMyTable
(Name)
Select
    Name
Output
    inserted.Name, Inserted.RoleNo
    into @MyNewRoles
From tblMyTableOfNames

select * from @MyNewRoles
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind adding a field to your table, you could generate a unique ID for each batch transaction (for example, a random UUID), and store that in the table as well. Then, to find the IDs associated with a given transaction you would just need something like

```
select my_id from my_table where batch_id = ?
```